# How to use a reference type value in a loop body

Tags: c#, .net

I introduced an interface in the constructor, then looped through a method to call the interface's methods, and finally used the interface's public properties, but this property is always changing. I know it's because of the reference variable.
Like the code below, is there a better design pattern to implement. thank you very much!

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

var f = new Factory(new StdOperation());
var stdCollection = new List<Std>{ new Std("aa"),
    new Std("bb/cc"),
    new Std("cc/dd"),
    new Std("dd/ee"),
    new Std("ee/ff")
};

f.Do(stdCollection);

foreach (var item in stdCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.NameAry?.Count);
}
//Output  0 0 0 2

public class Std
{
    public Std(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<string> NameAry { get; set; }
}

public class Factory
{
    private readonly IStudentOperation stdOpt;

    public Factory(IStudentOperation stdOpt)
    {
        this.stdOpt = stdOpt;
    }

    public void Do(List<Std> stdAry)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in stdAry)
        {
            if (!this.stdOpt.IsMatch(item.Name))
            {
                continue;
            }
            item.NameAry = this.stdOpt.NameAry;
        }
    }
}

public interface IStudentOperation
{
    List<string> NameAry { get; }

    bool IsMatch(string name);
}

public class StdOperation : IStudentOperation
{
    private List<string> _nameAry;

    public bool IsMatch(string name)
    {
        this._nameAry?.Clear();

        //do something...
        if (name.IndexOf("/") == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        this._nameAry = name.Split("/").ToList();
        return true;
    }

    public List<string> NameAry => this._nameAry;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing special about using a reference type value in a loop. Can you explain what this program is trying to accomplish, what it is supposed to output and what it does output? Maybe you can solve the problem yourself by [debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022) it.

Comment: While debugging have a hard look at `this._nameAry?.Clear();`. You brought the topic "reference" up. At what reference of the string list is __nameAry still looking?

Comment: Code smell. `IsMatch()` sounds like it would only do some checking, but inside you are clearing the data with `_nameAry.Clear()`. Please consider if this is appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for your issue is:

```
item.NameAry = this.stdOpt.NameAry;
```

`Factory` has a method `Do` that takes a whole list but has just a single `IStudentOperation` with a field `List<string> NameAry`. So you iterate one list and for every item in it you assign the same result list, so only the last one is correct.

Instead you could let `IsMatch` return the `NameAry` as an out-parameter:

```
public interface IStudentOperation
{
    bool IsMatch(string name, out List<string> matches);
}

public class StdOperation : IStudentOperation
{
    public bool IsMatch(string name, out List<string> matches)
    {
        if (name.IndexOf("/") == -1)
        {
            matches = new List<string>(0);
            return false;
        }
        matches = name.Split("/").ToList();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now `Do` can consume it in this way:

```
public void Do(List<Std> stdAry)
{
    foreach (var item in stdAry)
    {
        if (!this.stdOpt.IsMatch(item.Name, out var matches))
        {
            continue;
        }
        item.NameAry = matches;
    }
}
```

Now the result is as expected:

```
2
2
2
2
```

Comment: I would have simply nulled _nameAry  instead of clearing it. But an out Parameter not only fixes it but is the way better pattern here.

Comment: Good catch. A better name for `IsMatch` would be `TryMatch` as it follows the same naming convention often used in .NET as `TryParse`, `TryGetValue` etc.

Comment: Shouldn't the loop body in the `Do` method be `if (stdOpt.IsMatch(item.Name, out var matches)) { item.NameAry = matches; break; }`?

Comment: Better but it should not use break.

Comment: Yes, using Output can solve this problem. I also wondered if there would be a more elegant solution :)